# Display Progress bar while delay?

Tags: android, delay, progressdialog

In my app i want to have a delay of 5 seconds and in this five seconds user should see progress dialog
i tried this

```
    progressdialog.show();
  try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    progressdialog.dismiss();
```

but while Thread is sleeping the progessdialog also wont show  .

Comment: Whats the problem with writing code in onFinish?

Comment: use thread instead of current thread ,currently you are sleeping the current ui thread.

Comment: i used delay about 15-20 times in code so there  will be lots of changes i have to make . so  i am searching for alternate method

Comment: Well as mcd said, you have to use anotehr thread, I'd use a Handler to postDelayed, put the code into a method and call the method in the runnable run method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) {
            public void onFinish() {
               mProgressDialog.dismiss();
              // my whole code
            }

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }
        }.start();
```

This works fine

Answer (score 1):

```
        progressDialog.show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        },3000);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what the code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and more likely to attract upvotes.